# 404 error with ajax page loader

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I have an ajax posts loader on a page.  The link to call it looks like this:

```
<div class="load_more_cont">
  <p align="center">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/category/books/page/5/" title="Load more"><span class="fa fa-angle-down fa-fw button" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

and this is the ajax:

```
$('.load_more_cont a').on('click', function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();

//how many posts per page
var posts_per_page = 12;

//set button to contain spinning loading icon
$(this).html('<span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw loading" aria-hidden="true">');
console.log($(this).attr('href') + '#main_container');

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $(this).attr('href') + '#main_container',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(out)
    {
        //result of query
        result = $(out).find('#load_posts_container .home_post_box');

        //append result to posts container
        $('#load_posts_container').append(result).masonry( 'appended', result, true );

        //find the next link in the returned result
        nextlink = $(out).find('.load_more_cont a').attr('href');

        //if (nextlink != undefined)
        if (result['length'] == posts_per_page)
        {
            //add the next link to the load more button
            $('.load_more_cont a').attr('href', nextlink);
            $('.load_more_cont a').html('<span class="fa fa-angle-down fa-fw button" aria-hidden="true">');
        }
        else
        {
            //remove the load more button and add a clearing div
            $('.load_more_cont').remove();
            $('#load_posts_container').append('<div class="clear"></div>');
        }
    },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(thrownError);
   }
});
});
```

It work's fine but when I get to page 5 of the category (as above page 5 of books) I get a 404 error.  If I load the category url in the browser no issues - both page 5 and 6 exist and load.  Everything is on the same server.  If I don't select a category so the url looks like this `http://www.example.com/page/5/` then it also works just fine.  Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you checked `$(this).attr('href')` to ensure it is returning the correct path? You can `console.log($(this).attr('href'));` to have that print in the console or you can use the network section in your dev tools to monitor the ajax call.

Comment: That's in the code I posted.

Comment: And is it displaying the correct path? Have your checked the network in the dev tools? It must be a typo somewhere since 404 means it doesn't exist. Try removing the `#main_container` from the call.

Comment: Yes it is everytime.  This is what the console spits out with `#main_container` removed

`javascript.js:226 http://www.example.com/category/books/page/4/
javascript.js:226 http://www.example.com/category/books/page/5/
jquery-3.1.0.js:9392 GET http://www.example.com/category/books/page/5/ 404 (Not Found)send @ jquery-3.1.0.js:9392jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-3.1.0.js:8999(anonymous function) @ javascript.js:228jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-3.1.0.js:5110elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.0.js:4918
javascript.js:262 404
javascript.js:263 Not Found`

Comment: I'm looking on the website now. I see what you mean, that is very strange. I will continue to look around, if I find anything that could be causing this problem I will get back to you.

Comment: Although it starts with a request from the front-end, 404 is decided by the back-end, thus I think this is a back-end issue. You'll get better help if you show the relevant back-end code.

Comment: The backend is wordpress so requesting `http://www.example.com/category/books/page/5/` retrieves the category.php page in wordpress.  As i explained in the original question if i load `http://www.example.com/category/books/page/5/` directly in the browser everything works just fine so the php page is working.

Comment: Ok so I did go through category.php as well.  Nothing odd there but i discovered that wordpress has a 404 error bug related to permalinks of the category and tag pages so I think the issue might indeed be wordpress side.  The solution is to change the permalinks or resave them which I tried.  Didn't make any difference.  In parallel to that I did a GET request test from this site `https://www.hurl.it/` and `http://www.example.com/category/books/page/5/` returns a 404 BUT actually returns the full page with all 12 posts as well.  Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was a combination of the posts per page setting in wordpress (which I had set to 16), the way posts were displayed (I was displaying 12 per page) and how 404's were being handled (by index.php rather than by a 404.php page).  So in a sense getting a 404 from the GET with the full page was completely correct even though it seemed like a contradiction.  As soon as I gave wordpress a 404.php page I was able to separate the issues and then tracked down that page counts were incorrect because of the per page settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition here makes no sense imo: `if (result['length'] == posts_per_page)`. A pagination link is present if you have more than posts_per_page items left and not if its more or equal. If there are 5 items on the page and `posts_per_page = 5`, it does not mean that there is a next page.

Normally there should be no pagination link if you are on the last page, so the check should be like that

```
if ($(out).find('.load_more_cont a').length > 0) { ...
```

My guess is that you have `posts_per_page` amount of items on the last page and you set the next link to `undefined` resulting in an error.

Comment: The condition `if (result['length'] == posts_per_page)` is correct.  Result is only returning 12 per page so checking if its other than exactly equal and if so eliminating the link is correct.  But you are correct that 12 on the page does not mean that there is a next page.  I overlooked that so have swapped out the conditional for this `if (nextlink != "")` (similar to what you posted) which means I can lose posts_per_page as well.  Anyway none of this is the issue. The request for page 5 is the one that consistently fails - page 5 has 12 items on it (a full page) and page 6 has 4.